# Can I have more than 1 server alias or server name? ubuntu apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

Can I do this

```
ServerName example.com , www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com , www.example.com

or this

ServerName example.com
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com 
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

in the same example.conf

Comment: Your question is answered [in the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#servername).

Comment: ServerName might only have one name, but ServerAlias can have multiple, separated by spaces, not ,

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you read the excellent [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)?

`ServerName` might only have one name, but `ServerAlias` can have multiple, separated by spaces, not `,`.